# Making a colums total (SUM) with Views

Tags: views, 8

Popular Drupal 7 modules such as Views Calc and Views aggregate plus are not available for Drupal 8, so I'm struggling with achieving the following :

Making the sum of a column (of one integer field of list of child nodes) per parent node, without any custom code. No matter what I do with the "Use Aggregation" feature , I keep on getting a list of the values of entities meeting my criteria and not the sum.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my initial attempts, I tried to created a view on the child nodes to which I applied a contextual filter to limit the results to the parent node.  That didn't work.

In the end, the SUM worked, when I switched things around, I created a view on the parent, and establised a relation with the child nodes (through an entity reference).  When I summed up the field (of the child), it worked.

Comment: can you add print screen of your view..?

Comment: This worked for me. My view of "Child" type with a relation to the parent would not sum a dollar amount field I have on the Child nodes. I recreated the view as a "Parent" type with a relation to the child nodes, and I was then able to aggregate/sum the dollar amount fields.

Answer (score 2):

Your current configuration is doing the SUM of all numbers in that field but per views row, so you'd see numbers added up within each node if you had a multivalue field.

To make it sum up across all results/nodes you need to remove the Sort criteria, that can throw aggregation off.

---

I don't think your second question is making sense, you want to make a reference to a value calculated within views?

Entityreference creates a list of entities, and the summed up value is not an entity, you can't reference it like that. You can create a Views block and show the summed up value on some content pages and wherever you need it. Is that what you're after?

Comment: Thanks for answering, I appreciate it.  Regarding my second question.  I need  to check that the SUM remains below a treshold value, which is a field of the referenced entity. So I thought I would pull the Views sum to another field as an entity reference to the view...

Comment: Referenced entity or the one doing the referencing? Anyway I don't think Entityreference will let you do that, it expects nodes to be selected. Maybe you can use [Math Field](https://www.drupal.org/project/mathfield) but it still isn't clear where the comparison value is located.

Comment: The entity referenced (Parent)  in the entities I'm summing up (Children).  The parent also holds the field with the treshold. In short, I would need to get that sum into a field of another entity. Thanks for suggesting Math Field. It woudn't solve this problem, but another issue if have, if only it would be available for Drupal 8.... :-(

Comment: I see more clearly now, but this seems to be a wider issue than just sums in views. Maybe you can open a separate question and include all the relevant information, and what your goal is. Maybe Views isn't the way to go for you, maybe something else will turn up.

Comment: I tried to remove the sort criteria, but that didn't have any effect.  Issue remains...

Comment: Did you do that in Entityreference display? Aggregation doesn't make sense in there, try a Page or a Block and you'll get to the correct sum of all the nodes fields. Then you can try some other method to incorporate that number into other operations you need. [Computed field](https://www.drupal.org/project/computed_field) might help and it had alpha4 version for D8.

Comment: Tried switching to a Block, no effect.   Good idea to look at Computed field.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the Block configuration? I don't see why it would work on my end and not on yours.

Comment: Found it...  I had to create the view on the Parent, and not on the child (using the parent as contextual filter as I did...)