# Perform math calculation in views

Tags: views, 8

On Drupal 8 site, I have a exact copy of the below excel example table made with views but without the **yellow cell** yet.

[image: View table with calculation]

The view is displaying one content type: **Client** where all the below fields are available:

- Date
- Client Name
- Client ID
- Amount ($)

Now, as you can see, the yellow cell is displaying the **total SUM** of all **amount ($)** rows.
which basically is: 15+29+97+115+45+67+23+11+5+91+44 = 542$

How can i achieve this exact calculation in my view ?

I have tried to enable the **Use aggregation** option under the advanced section on my view, but it seems it doesn't do what i am asking for!

any help please ?

Note: I believe the use **Use aggregation** option doesn't add a row at the bottom of the table calculating the sum of all above rows and therefore this question [Making a colums total (SUM) with Views](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/272036/making-a-colums-total-sum-with-views) is not a possible duplicate of this one.

**UPDATE #1**

After following the answer of @Stef Van Looveren, I am encountering a new error:

```
InvalidArgumentException: Field field_money_amount is unknown. in Drupal\Core\Entity\ContentEntityBase->getTranslatedField() (line 587 of /home/####/public_html/#####/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/ContentEntityBase.php)
```

Knowing that: **field_money_amount** is the id of the field taken from the content type being used inside the view.

**Complete code in the .module file:**

```
<?php

use Drupal\views\ViewExecutable;

function my_module_views_pre_render(ViewExecutable $view){
  if ($view->id() == "view_id" && $view->current_display == 'display_id') {
    $total = 0;
    foreach ($view->result as $value) {
      $number = $value->_entity->get('field_money_amount')->value;
      $total += $number;
    }
    $view->attachment_after = [
      '#markup' => '<table class="table cols-0"><tr><td>Total:</td><td>'.$total.'</td></tr></table>',
      '#allowed_tags' => ['table','tr','td']
    ];
  }
```

}

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Making a colums total (SUM) with Views](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/272036/making-a-colums-total-sum-with-views)

Comment: @jdrupal It is not a duplicate at all, please check my above answer, I am obviously asking on how to add *a row at the bottom of the table calculating the sum of all above rows*, the referred question does not explain that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After further search, I have found [Views Aggregator](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_aggregator) module to do exactly what I need to do.

I am willing to accept @Stef Van Looveren answer especially where i prefer not to have to add a new module to my site but for some reason isn't working for me, unless somebody can help fix the above provided code.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question and a typical use case. In a custom module, do the following:

```
use Drupal\views\ViewExecutable;

function helper_views_pre_render(ViewExecutable $view){
  if ($view->id() == "numbers" && $view->current_display == 'page_1') {
    $total = 0;
    foreach ($view->result as $value) {
      $number = $value->_entity->get('field_number')->value;
      $total += $number;
    }
    $view->attachment_after = [
      '#markup' => '<table class="table cols-0"><tr><td>Total:</td><td>'.$total.'</td></tr></table>',
      '#allowed_tags' => ['table','tr','td']
    ];
  }
}
```

Change the names according to your view name & field names. I'm sure you get the point: you add a table below with the total result.

I did a test and it gave me the following result:

[image]

Comment: thank you for your reply, two simole question: (1) does the `function helper_views_pre_render(ViewExecutable $view)` will trigger everytime the view is being visited ? (2) I have more than 500 rows results in the view, so do you think `foreach` will affect the performance in a way or another ?

Comment: Dear @Stef Van Looveren, I have: (1) Added your above code to the 
**.module** file of my custom module. (2) Change the **View Name, Display Name & Field names** and (3) Clear all caches... but still when i visit the view, **nothing** appeared at the bottom of the table. any ideas why ?

Comment: Hi Aka, 1) Is the module enabled? 2) did you change helper_views_pre_render to mymodulename_views_pre_render, ...?

Comment: Dear @Stef Van Looveren, my mistake, i forget to change `helper_views_pre_render` to `mymodulename_views_pre_render` but can you please check the **UPDATE #1** of my question for a new error now available !!!